bsc usdt transferFrom Why is bnb not usdt transferred in the end? And the transfer amount is not controlled?
My environment:
ethers:6.13.1
next:14.2.3
bnb usdt contract address:0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955
When I used this token to transfer funds, I found that the transfer was bnb, so I should use usdt (I know that a certain amount of bnb is needed as gas)
enter image description here
Here is my relevant code:
// initialization ethers
export class Web3Service {
    provider: BrowserProvider;
    signer: JsonRpcSigner;
    address: string;

    constructor(windowEthereum: any) {
        this.provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(switchEthereumChain(windowEthereum))
        this.provider.getSigner().then(signer => {
            this.signer = signer;
            this.signer.getAddress().then((address: string) => {
                this.address = address
                console.log("address:", address)
            });
        });
    }

    getContract(readOnly: Boolean): Contract {
        if (!readOnly) {
            return new ethers.Contract(USDT_ADDRESS,
                ["function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)",
                    "function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)",
                    "function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)"],
                this.signer)
        } else {
            return new ethers.Contract(USDT_ADDRESS,
                ["function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256)",
                    "function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256)"],
                this.provider)
        }
    }
}

// transferFrom
function transferFrom() {
        const contract: Contract = web3Service.getContract(false)
        const amount = parseEther("0.0001");
        const account=web3Service.address
        // Unable to call estimated gas
        // const estimateGas = await contract.getFunction("transferFrom").estimateGas(account, CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount);
        let overrides = {
            gasLimit: 720000,
            gasPrice: 2000,
        };
        contract.getFunction("transferFrom").send(account, CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount, overrides)
            .then((result) => {
                setTransfer(jsonToString(result))
            }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('transferFrom error:', error);
        });
    }

I tried to print and load some content, the following is a screenshot. When I initiated transferFrom, the problem mentioned above occurred
enter image description here
Try:
Guess the bnb usdt contract address is wrong: after query verification, it is correct https://bscscan.com/address/0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955
I really don't know what's wrong
Expected: When calling transferFrom, the amount to be transferred should be "0.0001 USDT" and the gas fee should be bnb
